# Developing Patterns in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

How to create different patterns (like coverflow) in javascript? I don't want to use the already existing plugins provided by JQuery and other frameworks.
I want to try developing from scratch. Any place where I can get documentation or tutorials to start with ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? "Pattern" in programming has several different meanings. What exactly about coverflow would you like to emulate? The transition effect? The overlapping images? The 3D-ish slanted images?

Comment: Ok Here Patterns I meant , I have objects having same properties(10 to 20 divs ) and I want to display in Some good UI format , e.g. coverflow concept is , similar type of objects represented in nice UI . or YUI carousels. Can say Want to create Carousels. Hope it helps in understanding the question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

This article helped getting started with my first jquery plugin.

P.S.

Reading others code can help sometimes. Can be a great source of inspiration and motivation, too (because the the code you read is either so horrible or so shiny ...)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you are looking to create your own Javascript framework. If so, [try this page.](http://www.admixweb.com/2009/05/20/how-to-easily-create-a-javascript-framework-part-1/)

Comment: Not exactly framework , a reusable javascript which takes html div objects as input and presents it in Nice UI format. That Nice UI format I will come up with my own . I need general guidelines If I plan to do such thing, how to go abt it ?

And the link I guess It will help me understand the things better. Thanks for the link.